# Weird Behavior In Convergence of Neural Network in Tensorflow with SoftMax

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

So I am having a very weird problem in my neural network. I am essentially training a neural network to play the game Pong from scratch. Now I've managed to make it converge, and it plays fairly well, but then I changed one of tf calls to another one, which I thought was equivalent, and I can't for the life of me figure out why the later one ends up diverging horribly (The pong racket just ends up at the top without moving).

The only difference I do is one line. This is my neural network structure that converges:

```
    h = tf.layers.dense(
        self.observations,
        units=hidden_layer_size,
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    self.probability = tf.layers.dense(
        h,
        units=2,
        activation = tf.nn.softmax,
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

And then I define the log loss on self.probability, and optimize that loss function, very standard stuff. But then if I change the self.probability to:

```
    self.probability = tf.nn.softmax(tf.layers.dense(
        h,
        units=2,
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()))
```

Then for some reason all hell breaks loose and I diverge really badly. Isn't passing the activation function as tf.nn.softmax essentially wrapping the output tensor into the softmax function just like the later example?! Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using cross entropy loss?

Comment: It must be absolutely the same. Can you make a reproducible example?